# You haven't voted on questions in a while; questions need votes too!

Tags: support, popup

Why I am spammed with the following message?

> [image]

Well, they don't necessarely need votes. I am *free* to judge when a question need to be voted.

---

Is this something new or I have reached a threshold to activate this message?

I don't think that after more than 19.000 votes I need a reminder about voting.

Comment: There's quite a few messages I've been seeing lately that I feel as an experienced user I don't need. It really uglies up the page. Experienced users typically have thousands and thousands of votes, we don't need reminders of a functionality we know exists in my opinion.

Comment: I remember seeing that popup more than a few times. It's not new. It's kinda harmless, isn't it?

Comment: @yivi it's definitely harmless, per se. But it doesn't make me want to vote, the question quality does. I get these kinds of messages in games I play too, like "you haven't finished this mission" while I'm mid mission. Like, I know, don't rub it in [game]. I'm sure others feel differently, but personally, I'm not a fan of this but I'm not going to make a fuss over a trivial popup.

Comment: [Definitely not new](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157061/how-to-not-show-the-message-you-havent-voted-on-questions-in-a-while-question). It seems silly on SO.. I rarely think, oh thank goodness someone else copy/pasted that error message so eloquently... that deserves upvotes. Actually, I think we need _more_ reminders.. "You haven't favorited in awhile; questions _like_ being the favorite!", "You haven't close-voted in awhile; this question needs it!", "You're not drinking enough water; it's creepy that we know that!", etc.

Comment: Is this a bad time to mention I have a water bottle that reminds me via bluetooth that I need to drink more water? I'm bad about drinking water..

Comment: @SterlingArcher I hope it comes with a companion mobile app with social integration! If you're not getting credit for drinking, you're doing it wrong. ;)

Comment: @vivat wait what? I've been maintaining my own fluid levels for 32 years **like an animal**?

Comment: I just saw this message on two questions in a row, despite dismissing the notification the first time.  So I went to meta to learn more.  I just up-voted your question, and I hope that prevents me from seeing the message again.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This has existed [**since time immemorial**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/05/06/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/), and the threshold to trigger it doesn't have appeared to have changed all that much.

If you can't find questions which are worthy of your vote - either up *or* down - then ignore the pop-up.  Just be aware that it'll come back if you don't vote on questions every now and then.

Comment: Correct: it doesn't specify up *or down* votes. "Questions need downvotes too", fortunately. Lots of them do.

Comment: Intresting. I am surprised that I haven't seen this message until now.

Comment: If one cannot find a question which deserves a vote, do you know if voting on a question then undoing the vote suffices?